# multiple row of charts in ggplot without using facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a chart that is too wide, and instead I want to cut it into half and display it as two charts, one using the first half of the range of the x scale and the second using the second half. Is there an easy way to do it?

An example would be `ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price)) + geom_bar()` , where instead of having a chart showing price range of 0 to 20000 as produced by the line above, I want to have one for price 0 to 10000 and another from 10000 to 20000 below it. It should look like something `facet_wrap`ped but there is no different variable to facet here.

**EDIT**: in my actual chart (not using `diamonds`), I use also `coord_flip()`, which apparently causes problems with some otherwise valid attempt. I'd love to have an answer that can also work with `coord_flip()` (i.e: one chart to the left, and the other to the right, instead of stacking vertically)

Comment: How about adding another variable you can use for facetting?

Comment: I prefer not to since then I'll have to remove the facet strip header.

However, I did try that, creating a TRUE/FALSE variable to facet in my actual dataset (equivalent to TRUE for 0-10000 and FALSE 10000-20000 in price in diamonds data set above). The result is that the range in each facet strip is still the full range, but one strip has the second half empty and the other the first half empty, rather than two strips with different ranges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(data.table) # not necessary, but better.

data(diamonds)
setDT(diamonds)

p1 = ggplot(diamonds[price > 0 & price <= 10000], aes(x=price)) + geom_bar()
p2 = ggplot(diamonds[price > 10000 & price < 20000], aes(x=price)) + geom_bar()

grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

Comment: Thanks! this works great! Is it possible also to arrange horizontally, rather than vertically?

Comment: grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)